# React Router - Mapping routes with 404 error page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I am currently using React Router. I prefer the syntax of a routes config file and mapping over the array of routes to render the Route, as opposed to the `<Switch>` option.

```
{routes.map(route => {
        return (
          <PrivateRoute
            key={route.path}
            path={route.path}
            exact
            component={route.component}
          />
        );
      })}
```

Is there a way with the above use case to have a 404 component for all non-exact matching routes.

I have seen the `<Switch>` approach like this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match. As mentioned I prefer declaring all routes in a route config file, with the path, component and breadcrumb name. If I go down the Switch route then the route config is only used for breadcrumbs and becomes less useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to be defining your routes in a config file, then you should probably use [react-router-config](https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config) (which is also part of react-router)

If you have a peek at the implementation of [`renderRoutes`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-config/modules/renderRoutes.js), then you will notice that it internally uses a `Switch` component, which means that you can put your "404" routes at the end of the list and it should fallback to that one if there is no other match, for instance:

```
const routes = [
  {
    component: Root,
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: "/child/:id",
        component: Child,
        routes: [
          {
            path: "/child/:id/grand-child",
            component: GrandChild
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        component: NotFound,
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

You could also implement a component like this `RedirectToNotFound`:

```
const RedirectToNotFound = () => <Redirect to="/404" />;
```

And then setup your config file like this:

```
const routes = [
  {
    component: Root,
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: "/child/:id",
        component: Child,
        routes: [
          {
            path: "/child/:id/grand-child",
            component: GrandChild
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "/404",
        component: NotFound
      },
      {
        path: "*",
        component: RedirectToNotFound,
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Full disclosure: I've never used `react-router-config` and [unless you have a very specific need](https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config#motivation) I wouldn't recommend its usage.